# Can't Install Eventmachine On Synology DiskStation With OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, linux, openssl, rubygems, eventmachine

I'm trying to install the EventMachine ruby gem on my Synology DiskStation DS211 Linux-based NAS, but the installation fails while trying to create the Makefile for the native extension, saying:

> ```
> > gem install eventmachine --pre
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
>         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
>         /opt/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> checking for main() in -lssl... *** extconf.rb failed ***
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
> necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
> details.  You may need configuration options.
> ```

The contents of mkmf.log:

> ```
> package configuration for openssl is not found
> ```

---

Ruby and OpenSSL were both installed successfully on the machine using Optware `ipkg` to the default `/opt` directory.

I suspect that EventMachine fails due to OpenSSL being installed in an unexpected directory, but it is unclear which combination of configuration options and values are necessary to specify the correct location.

Some environment details:

> ```
> > ruby -v
> ruby 1.9.1p243 (2009-07-16 revision 24175) [arm-linux-eabi]
>
> > openssl version
> OpenSSL 0.9.8p 16 Nov 2010
>
> > which openssl
> /opt/bin/openssl
> ```

Has anyone else had any luck installing EventMachine in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need install openssl-dev package:

```
ipkg install openssl-dev
```

openssl-dev contains package configuration(openssl.pc) and header files.

Comment: Well, that answers the original question. Now I've got a new problem: the installation now fails with `checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***`